# Use a for loop to set columns of a table

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I currently define the tables and columns of a PostgreSQL database like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Float, Integer
Base = declarative_base()
class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "my_table"
    col_1 = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    col_2 = Column(Float)
    col_3 = Column(Float)
    col_4 = Column(Float)
    col_5 = Column(Float)
    # ....
    col_24 = Column(Float)
    col_25 = Column(Float)
```

Instead of writing the same identical lines multiple times, I would like to use a for loop that sets similar columns:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Float, Integer
Base = declarative_base()
class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "my_table"
    col_1 = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    for ind in range(2, 26):
        # set col_$ind
        ????
```

What should I do put inside the for loop to set the attributes `col_$ind` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Database on the fly with scripting languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580497/database-on-the-fly-with-scripting-languages)

Comment: as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519807/setting-a-class-attribute-with-a-given-name-in-python-while-defining-the-class/20608050#20608050) comment,  `vars()` may be the solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `vars()`:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Float, Integer
Base = declarative_base()
class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "my_table"
    col_1 = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    for ind in range(2, 26):
        # set col_$ind
        vars()[f"col_{ind}"] = Column(Float)
```

Answer (score 1):

Totally reasonable aim – as a software developer, your goal is to be efficient with your code. However, as you interact more deeply with relational databases, you may find value in explicit (though redundant) definitions.

**Notwithstanding, here is how you may achieve loop-wise table definition:**

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Float, Integer

Base = declarative_base()

# Define your class here
class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "my_table"
    
    # define your primary key
    col_1 = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, comment='primary key')


# Create columns with a loop
for i in range(2, 26):
    setattr(MyTable, f'col_{i}', Column(Float))
```